# Get Hit Count of any url / resource using web crawler

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I have made web crawler in java. It traverse through the links present in each page recursively. Now i want to get the count of hits a particular page got. Is it possible via web crawler? since we don't have any access to server code, we can't add any counter to count the hits. Please suggest any solution. Thanks.

Basic Structure of code is :

-> get the html source code of url.
  -> find the reachable links from html code and put it in a list.
  -> take the next link from list and continue the same till the list becomes empty.

I just want to show the hit count for each link.

Comment: @SriHarshaKappala you can see the basic structure.

Comment: Every time you get a link, send it to a host, put that link into a structure (fot instance, an array), with a counter... if when inserting, if that link is already present, increment that counter...

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can suggest is to wrap your link into a class, let it have a variable called counter to keep record of it. So basically you will have a list of the `Link` class. Example below:

```
public class Link{
    private String url;
    private int count = 0;

    public Link(String url){
        this.url = url; // initialise your link class with a url
    }

    public String getUrl(){
        increment();
        return url;
    }

    public void increment(){
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}
```

Then count it like this:

```
List<Link> links.... // initialise your links

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(links.get(i).getUrl()).get();
```

This way, everytime your url is accessed, the count is incremented to keep record of total hits.